# How to get some first characters and the rest of the characters in two different variables in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, decimal-point

I have number which has 18 decimal points.
I want to get the digits before the decimal points in a variable and the digits after the decimals in another variable.

Let's say the original variable value is 100,

I want to show that like this `100.000000000000000000` but now I am getting `100000000000000000000` (without decimal point)

I am trying to print the digits before the decimal points in a HTML element and the rest in another HTML

```
<div class="original"></div>

var original = data['result'];
$(".original").html(original]);
```

This prints `100000000000000000000` in the element original and that's fine.

Now I want to  print the digits before the decimal points in a HTML element 'beforeDecimal' and point then the rest

So my mark up is:

```
<div class="beforeDecimal"></div> . <div class="afterDecimal"></div>

var beforeDecimal = data['result']; // how do I have to change this ?
$(".beforeDecimal").html(beforeDecimal]);

var afterDecimal = data['result']; // how do I have to change this ?
$(".afterDecimal").html(afterDecimal]);
```

if I use `var beforeDecimal = parseFloat(data['result']).toFixed(4);` is shows `100.00000000000e+21` but I want `100 . 000000000000000000`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Turns out that the number should be considered a string...
Because the entire AND the decimals (always 18) are "merged" (the dot is removed).

Additionally... We are working with a "too big" integer for simple JS.
So here comes [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) which enables us to turn that big number into a string without error.

Then, that is just sub-string management!

That was a good one!
;)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Our start point...
  var data = [];
  data['result'] = 2287852333330000000000;

  // To see why use "bigInt" library !!!
  var numberWRONG = data['result'].toString();
  console.log("numberWRONG: "+numberWRONG);


  var number = bigInt(data['result']);
  console.log(number);
  
  numberString = number.toString();
  console.log(numberString);

  // Now were ok to just string manipulate... Knowing we always have 18 decimals.
  
  // Get the lenghts.
  var numberLength = numberString.length;
  var entireLength = numberLength - 18;
  var decimalLength = numberLength - entireLength;
  
  // cut the sub-strings.
  var entire = numberString.substr(0,entireLength);
  var decimals = numberString.substr(entireLength,numberLength);
  
  // Append the parts in the right divs.
  $(".beforeDecimal").html(entire);
  $(".afterDecimal").html(decimals);
});
```

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
}
.beforeDecimal{
  color:blue;
}
.afterDecimal{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/big-integer/1.6.26/BigInteger.min.js"></script>

<div class="beforeDecimal"></div> . <div class="afterDecimal"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting this "100.28785233333e+21" if I use yours

Comment: this is what I am using now and getting the above results `var number = data['result'];
   var entire = Math.floor(number);
   var decimals = (number-entire)*1E18;
   
   $(".beforeDecimal").html(entire);
   $(".afterDecimal").html(decimals);`

Comment: `data['result'];` has 100 and 18 zeros

Comment: Yes... I noticed an error in the decimals in my example too. I think you will need something to handle big integers... Look for [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)

Comment: Ho... If the decimals are all zeros... mmm.

Comment: not all decimals are zeros.. I just say for an example.. decimals have all the numbers actually

Comment: actually `var number = 100;` should be `var number = 100123456789123456789;` when we create logic ..

Comment: Ho... The dot is not present?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162434/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-riffaz-starr).

Comment: I am getting the value without dot and I have put/add that DOT to show the number as 18 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

If your number is represented as a javascript string, you can do

```
const [before, after] = floatAsString.split('.');
```

If it is a number, you use

```
const [before, after] = float.toFixed(18).split('.');
```

I would advice against using floating point calculations that involve subtraction, because they can yield small errors in the output. Consider the following example:

```
const float = 1.4543;
const integerPart = float | 0; // this removes the fractional part
const fraction = float - integerPart;
console.log(fraction); // logs 0.4542999999999999, which is not the actual fraction, but is very close to it
```

Comment: up voted... @louys answer solved the issue perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Number.toFixed(len)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Number/toFixed)

```js
let a = (100).toFixed(18).toString().split('.');
document.body.innerHTML = a[0]+' | ' + a[1];
```

Comment: thanks for this.. I want to style the 100 in a color and the rest digits in another color.. so I want them in two different variables ...

Comment: and `data['result'];` gives `100000000000000000000` I can not get just 100 only I will get 100 with 18 zeros

Comment: Just add a .split to separate the string to 100 and 000000
Snippet edited